# Changing wordpress old images path url doesn't reflect in my database using SQL

Tags: php, wordpress

I have set a new cdn to serve images `cdn.example.net` . all my new uploads works fine with it , but my old images has path `example.net` .

I tried to use `WP_CONTENT_URL` to change images but it reflects in plugins,themes file to be broken . so I needed to upload all my plugins,themes files [That's not a good option as every new plugin I'll need to install , I will need to uploads it's files ] .

I tried using SQL `UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE (post_content,'http://example.net/blog','http://cdn.example.com.net');` . it tells me that there is `row matched` but with `no rows affected`

Comment: do you have wp cli install ?

Comment: yes. to explain more I don't want to change `SITE_URL` , I just want to adjust old images url to `cdn` url as explained

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this issue by editing my `wp-config.php`

First one will change all [Images,Plugins,Themes] path to another url , your cdn as an example

```
define( 'WP_CONTENT_URL', 'your_cdn_website_url/wp-content' );
```

I left this url so old one so plugins won't be broken

```
define( 'WP_PLUGIN_URL', 'your_website_url/wp-content/plugins' );
```